# Find the vector so that it is parallel

Tags: vector-spaces

Find a vector with length 7 and is parallel to the line $y=\frac{12}{13}x-1$

Is there some more advanced mathematics behind this than elementary maths or?

Could use a nudge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line $y=12/13 x$ is parallel to the line $y=12/13x -1$. Consider a vector in it, for example $(13, 12)$. Divide it by its length and multiply by 7.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick!

Comment: @Paze You are welcome.